# What can I do if visa is issued after the intended date of travel?

Tags: visas, schengen, delays

Can I go directly to my main destination without going to member state of first entry in Schengen area? What can I do if visa is issued after the intended date of travel? How can I change my first entry to my main destination?

From comments...

I didn't received my visa from France (Main Destination) yet, in application I have filled spain as my first entry. If my visa is issued from france then is it possible to travel directly to france without going to spain?

Comment: You can change your date of travel, you can cancel your visa and apply again, or you can cancel your travel.

Comment: I didn't recived my visa from France (Main Destination) yet, in application I have filled spain as my first entry. If my visa is issued from france then is it possible to travel directly to france without going to spain?

Comment: Yes, if your itinerary changes after you apply, but your main destination is still France, you can travel directly to France.